# show count of only configurable products of current category

Tags: magento, categories, product

i want to show count of only configurable products of current category on category page. for that I have written following code...

```
<?php $cate = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();

                $total=0;


               $category = Mage::registry('current_category');

               $products = $category->getProductCollection();

              foreach ( $products as $_product )
                 if ($_product->isConfigurable())
                 {
                    $total++;
                 }
                 echo $cate."(".$total.")"; ?>
```

my problem is the code is showing the total count of configurable products of all child categories... can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is the category in question an anchor category?

Comment: yes, this is an anchor category..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
$cate       = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
$total      = 0;
$category   = Mage::registry('current_category');

$products = $category->getProductCollection();

foreach ( $products as $_product ){
    if ($_product->getType_id()=="configurable"){
        $total++;
    }
}
 echo $cate."(".$total.")"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$products = $category->getProductCollection()
          ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');
$total = $products->getSize();
echo $this->__('%s (%d)', $category->getName(), $total);
```

Comment: same problem.... i think there may be some problem with the object returned by the line `$category = Mage::registry('current_category');` i tried to print the result using print_r but it shows nothing....

Comment: You are likely to get an overflow or memory limit problem with printing complex objects, try `print_r($category->debug())`